# Url.Action generates a wrong url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use the Url.Action method to generate a Url string.

[image]

Thats the result:

```
"/Home/GetRejectTest/0?IsSelected=False"
```

The controller and action name are correct but the query parameters are screwed up. Is this because The action does not have a RouteAttribute thus query parameters are generated?

My action:

```
   public ActionResult GetRejectTest(Test test)
        {
            return new EmptyResult();

        }
```

Test class has those 3 properties Id, Name, IsSelected.

My route definition:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: what is `urlHelper` ?

Comment: Show the action method signature and the relevant registered routes

Comment: Its System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper

Comment: what is values ?. From your screenshot, it looks like the dictionary has 0 and null values for Name and Id. So whatever you are getting is the expected result. Isn't it ?

Comment: I would expect /id/0 or ?id=0

Comment: Assuming `values` is a new default instance of `Test`, (and your using the Default route `{controller}/{action}/{id}`), then the url **is** correct

Comment: Is correct means what format? I have url default route and still the url is broken.

Comment: @Pascal, The url you have shown is exactly what should be created assuming `values=new Test()` - `Test` has an `id` property which matches the `{id}` placeholder in the default route, but there are no route placeholders for `{name}` or `{IsSelected}` so those values are added as query string parameters (but because `Name` is null, its not added)

Comment: the generated url `/Home/GetRejectTest/0` matches with your route pattern `{controller}/{action}/{id}`. This is the expected behavior. `/Home/GetRejectTest/0` is same as `/Home/GetRejectTest?id=0` when it comes to processing the request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The url your generating (`/Home/GetRejectTest/0?IsSelected=False`) is correct for your route definition. You passing a new instance of `Test` to the `Url.Action()` method, which

1. Internally builds a dictionary based on the name and value
   (using`.ToString()`) of each property in your model - i.e.
   `controller=Home, action=GetRejectTest, id=0, Name=null, IsSelected=False`
2. Then searches your route definitions for a match which it finds
   (`url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"`) and updates the placeholders
   (which at this point generates `/Home/GetRejectTest/0`) but your
   route definition does not have url parameters for `Name` and
   `IsSelected` so these are added as query string parameters (because
   `Name` is `null`, a query string for that propery is not generated)
   so the result is now `/Home/GetRejectTest/0?IsSelected=False`

You have not indicated what result you're actually expecting, but creating specific route definitions will solve most cases. For example if you want

```
/Home/GetRejectTest/0/false
```

or `/Home/GetRejectTest/0/false/someName` if the value of `Name` is not `null`, then you can create an additional route (which must be before the default route)

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Test",
  url: "Home/GetRejectTest/{id}/{isselected}/{name}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetRejectTest", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Note that because `Name` is typeof `string` and therefore can be `null`, the `{name}` placeholder needs be the last one and marked as `UrlParameter.Optional` (otherwise it will revert back to using query string parameters)

Comment: Ok now I understand it. That I used id as query param in myself was just stupid then ;-) Thanks for your reasonable explanation.